# Style - How to differentiate event types

Tags: javascript

Simple naming convention question.

I have two event systems under the same global variable.

```
NS
```

one abstracts dom events the other is a basics pub/sub system.

Each has it's own list of methods.

One I plan to name Event like this.

```
NS.Event.trigger(name);
```

The other I plan to name like this.

```
NS.EventDom.add(type, func);
```

Are these good names?  I need good API names and wanted to follow the Noun/Verb convention.

Would `NS.EventD.add(type, func)` work?

Are abbreviations O.K?

Another option would be

```
NS.Event
```

and

```
NS.Ev
```

Comment: I'm sure some one , some where, has done a study on how to create API's that are easy to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard question to answer definitively since APIs and naming are two of the truly hard things in Computer Science (I think there's a proper quote about that somewhere, but anyway...).

I would go for some sort of consistency with the names, such as `DomEvent` and `XXXEvent`, where XXX is something descriptive about the kind of event it is, eg- `XhrEvent` or `ServerEvent`. `EventDom` doesn't sound right to me.  `DomEvent` sounds more like proper English to me and using this style would be idiomatic Java (if not JavaScript).

And I would not use abbreviations in the names.  `Ev` has no meaning to me.

Comment: El is commonly used for element so I thought Ev for Event, also I'm a native English speaker but it has always seemed strange that the naming is usually SPECEFIC-GENERAL instead of GENERAL-SPECEFIC ...  the general to specific has a cross relation to the general-specific you see in OO design.

Comment: Well, I'd argue that the XXXEvent naming style is not general-specific or specific-general in this case. Rather it is kind-thing.  The kind is not necessarily more specific, but rather a pseudo-typing mechanism. And the XXX part could also be applied to other things, like XXXListener, XXXHandler, XXXRequest, etc.

Comment: you don't think a kind is more specific?...like a Macintosh Apple? ...or Apple Macintosh.

Comment: I wouldn't say so necessarily because you could have a ServerEvent, a ServerRequest, a ServerFacade, etc (and similar with a ClientXXX).